# getopt() C function not working correctly in Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: c, getopt

This has been driving me crazy for a while cause it was working fine before on Ubuntu until I upgraded to Ubuntu 23.10. I'm calling the `getopt()` function in C without any loop and only once in the program and it always scans past non-option values. I wrote a minimal reproducible issue as such

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int opt = getopt(argc, (char **)argv, "hdeb:vg:wc:-");
  printf("Opt = %d, %d\n", opt, optind);
  return 0;
}
```

When called with program as `program -d test`, it prints out:

```
Opt = 100, 2
```

That looks fine because the last index where it found an option is 1.

However when I call it with as `program test -d`, deliberately putting the option after a non-option argument which by documentation is supposed to stop scanning at the non-option argument until I call `getopt()` again, it outputs:

```
Opt = 100, 3
```

The expected output is:

```
Opt = 100, 2
```

I tested further with `program test test2 test3 -d`, and the output was:

```
Opt = 100, 5
```

As you can see, `getopt()` keeps scanning past the non-option arguments like if there some kind of internal automatic loop.

I'm I missing something?? Has `getopt()` been redefined by new standards??

Comment: Which language are you actually using? Remove the tag for the other language, please. For further info, read the tags' descriptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm I missing something??

Yes.

> Has `getopt()` been redefined by new standards??

No.

What you're describing is a longstanding behavior of [GNU's implementation of `getopt()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html), which is what you will get in most Linux distributions:

> By default, `getopt()` permutes the contents of `argv` as it scans, so
> that eventually all the nonoptions are at the end.  Two other scanning
> modes are also implemented.  If the first character of optstring is
> '+' or the environment variable `POSIXLY_CORRECT` is set, then option
> processing stops as soon as a nonoption argument is encountered. [...]

The `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable modifies the behavior of a lot of other GNU software too, to disable GNU extensions and / or alter behavior to conform more closely to POSIX.  Possibly you are used to working in an environment where that is set by default.  Evidently, it is *not* set in the environment you are working in now.

Comment: What is it supposed to be set to?? Cause I tried it and it still behaves the same.

Comment: @RichardOre the value doesn't matter.  That it is set at all is enough.  I'd probably set it to `yes` or `true` or `1` for clarity.  Be sure to `export` it, otherwise it is only set for the current shell itself, not in the environment of other programs you launch from the shell.

Comment: I tried setting the environment variable to 1 and yes and the behavior remains the same.

Comment: OMG! I totally forgot. Been a while I've developed on linux and out of touch with it. The environment variable didn't work, but yes as evident in some of my past codebase, the `+` as first character was the magic. You pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!